# Using x86 Assembly (s file) with clang

Tags: assembly, compilation, x86, clang, llvm-ir

I have a problem with clang and compiling/linking/preprocessing several files together.

Working situation:

If all of them are `.c` files, then I can use

```sh
clang -c -g -emit-llvm myfile1.c myfile2.c myfile3.c
# outputs myfile1.bc myfile2.bc myfile3.bc
```

Then, I'm linking with

```sh
llvm-link myfile1.bc myfile2.bc myfile3.bc -o merged.bc
```

However, I cannot do the same, if one of my files is an x86 assembly file.

```sh
clang -c -g -emit-llvm myfile4.s
```

Produces `myfile4.o` as an output. When I try to link them using `llvm-link`, I have the following output:

```sh
llvm-link: myfile4.o:1:1: error: expected top-level entity
ELF SOME GIBBERISH...
```

I need those `.s` files and I don't know how can I use this method. I have looked at [this link](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2008-March/012958.html) and also to [this link too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288251/is-it-possible-to-translate-an-assembly-language-to-llvm-ir-optimize-it-and-the).

Is there any method, way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You can't assemble x86 asm into LLVM-IR / bytecode.  That would basically be a decompiler and LLVM doesn't include that.

Comment: Is there any decompiler that does such a thing? I am assuming that I need to decompile it to `.c` first

Comment: Yes there are decompilers that can produce C.  Google it.  IDK if there are any that are good and free.  If your file was written in asm for a reason like needing to do non-standard stuff, it might not be possible.

Comment: I was trying to do fuzzing and injecting instructions into the assembly file. I want to see whether any injected instructions have any effect on the code or not.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you just compile it into an executable for that machine, instead of trying to make portable bytecode out of it?  Doesn't `clang -g -O2 *.c *.s -o testprog` work?